# mchem Double Subscript Error

Tags: packages, subscripts, mhchem

I've had a look at the other double subscript error questions here and they don't seen to solve my error. When I simplify what I want the suggested answer works, but then I don't get what I would like to display.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
n_{\ce{NH3}}=n_{\ce{NH3}_\text{initial}}-n_{\ce{HCl}}=0.3\text{ milimoles}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

What I'd like it to have the moles of NH3 subscripted by the word initial. If I remove the `\ce` command it works but messes up the representation of the NH3.

Comment: Try adding an extra brace layer: `n_{\ce{NH3}}=n_{{\ce{NH3}}_\text{initial}}-n_{\ce{HCl}}=0.3\text{ milimoles}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Phelype-Oleinik is there a way I can close it?

Comment: @SvenskTacoma When I voted to close the question, other users received a notification to vote to close (or not). When 5 users voted to close, the question was put `[on hold]` (see the tag appended to the title?). If the question stays on hold for enough time, it will be closed automatically.